# Como identificar em um shell script, qual é o comando docker que está sendo executado

Tags: shell-script, docker

Eu criei essa imagem (https://hub.docker.com/r/keviocastro/elgg-docker/~/dockerfile/) que configura um ambiente para uma aplicação web de rede social.

Essa aplicação necessita de um link com um container Mysql.

No Dockerfile da minha imagem (https://github.com/keviocastro/elgg-docker/blob/master/2.0.0-beta.3/Dockerfile) existe um comando RUN com um shell script que instala e configura a aplicação, conforme o trecho abaixo:

```
COPY . /elgg-docker/
RUN chmod +x /elgg-docker/elgg-install.sh
RUN /elgg-docker/elgg-install.sh
```

Nesse shell script contém um trecho de código que aguarda o servidor mysql responder para continuar a instalação da aplicação:

```
#wait for mysql
i=0
while ! netcat $ELGG_DB_HOST $MYSQL_PORT >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null; do
  i=`expr $i + 1`
  if [ $i -ge $MYSQL_LOOPS ]; then
    echo "$(date) - ${ELGG_DB_HOST}:${MYSQL_PORT} still not reachable, giving up."
    exit 0
  fi
  echo "$(date) - waiting for ${ELGG_DB_HOST}:${MYSQL_PORT}... $i/$MYSQL_LOOPS."
  sleep 1
done
```

O meu problema é que quando eu compilo a imagem com o comando "docker build -t keviocastro/elgg-docker ." O shell script de instalação é executado, e no trecho que verifica se o servidor mysql está disponivél retorna erro e então o build da imagem não é concluído.

Como eu posso identificar, no shell script ou alguma outra solução, que o comando que está sendo executado é Docker build e portando o trecho de aguardar o servidor mysql não precisa ser executado?

Comment: você pode colocar a saída do comando de build do docker?

Answer (score 1):

Voce tem que colocar o seu script ou no comando `CMD` ou no `ENTRYPOINT` do seu Dockefile.

O comando `RUN` sempre vai executar os comandos durante a build da imagem e "comitar" uma nova layer dessa imagem.

Veja mais informacoes na documentacao do Dockerfile:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/